# n-surface represented as 2 level sets of different functions, prove the gradients of these functions at each point are lineary dependent

Tags: differential-geometry

I took this exercise from the book Elementary Topics in Differential Geometry from J.A. Thorpe.

I have to show that if an n-surface $S$ is represented both as $f^{-1}(c)$ and $g^{-1}(d)$ where $\nabla f(p) \neq 0$ and $\nabla g(p) \neq 0$ for all $p\in S$. Then we have that for each $p \in S$, $\nabla f(p) = \lambda \nabla g(p)$ for some real number $\lambda \neq 0$.

My work on it. I believe I have to use the Lagrange Multiplier Theorem but I believe I can only use it when the point $p$ is a extreme point of $g$, so I guess I have to prove that all points $p$ are extreme points of g, which is where I get lost.
Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: "... I have to use Lagrange ..."?  No!  And the result is false for a general $S^n\subset\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: I might have explained the question badly! let me edit it because I spotted an error

Comment: Is the implicit function theorem available to you? If so (since $f$ and $g$ are presumably $C^1$), that guarantees your level set is a manifold of codimension one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Lagrange multiplier then maximize $f$ subject to the constraint $g(x)-d=0$. Each point that satisfies this constraint is an element of $S$. By Lagrange multiplier theorem we get
$$\nabla f(x)=\lambda \nabla g(x)$$
for all $x$ that maximizes $f$ subject to the constraint. In other word to all $x \in S$. As both vector fields are non zero in $S$, we get that $\lambda(p)$ is non zero for all $p\in S$.

Comment: Notice that $f$ is constant for elements that satisfy the constraint $ (f(x)=c)$ hence every element that satisfies the constraint is a maximal point of $f$ subject to the constraint.